# How to change the size of the Intellij Idea menu lines?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, width, jetbrains-ide

I would like to know how to change the space between lines of the menu (width). My menus having lines too big. There is image to show it.

[image]

Comment: What is inside your Help | About window? What's the version of OS, JDK, IDE?

Comment: Windows 10. JDK 8. Intellij IDEA 2018.3.5 Ultimate.

Comment: Looks like you're using the Material Theme plugin, which is not maintained or supported by JetBrains. Please direct your question to the author of the plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like yole said, the Material Theme Plugin change the space between each line in menu.

To fix it:

- Open IntelliJ settings (Ctrl + Alt +S)
- Appearance & Behavior > Material Theme > Tabs Compact
- Enable Compact Menus & Compact Dropdown Lists

Comment: Thank you! It solved. Now the menus are back to normal.

Comment: You can also use Tools -> Material Theme -> Panel Options -> Compact menus, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following worked:

Settings >> Material Theme UI >> Settings >> Compact >> tick Compact Menus :)